# Can someone clarify what the linear assumption of PCA is?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, assumptions, rbf-kernel, linearity

For the past few hours I've been trying to search what this linear assumption is. Some of the articles states that that your independent variables have to be **linear in relationship** and need some type of transformation if there is no linearity. Other articles state that your data has to be **linearly separable**. Which is it? Is it both?

Does it mean that that you first have to check if the independent variables are linear in relationship, then after applying PCA, check if the data is linearly separable?

OR

Check if the data, **before** applying PCA, is linearly separable with techniques like linear programming.

Then there is KERNEL PCA which after searching states that it is an extension of PCA where it is applied to **nonlinear data**. Does that mean nonlinear in relationship or linear **in**separable?

Comment: it depends on what you're doing because PCA will work on any data, linear or not, and will produce PCs that are orthogonal. it's just without some sort of linear relationship this won't be useful in some applications such as dimensionality reduction

Comment: @Aksakal You're right about everything except the "won't be useful" part.  PCA can be effective for dimension reduction even in the presence of strong nonlinearity.  For instance, take your favorite worst-case nonlinear relation in $d$ dimensions and embed it in a $d$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{d+k},$ perhaps adding some noise to it afterwards.  PCA will identify that subspace.

Comment: @whuber, maybe it's better not to qualify the relationship as "linear", i meant that if there's no relationship then dimensionality reduction will be limited

Comment: Since you're saying that my variables just have to have some relationship to apply PCA, should I still check if my data is linearly separable before applying linear PCA?

Comment: No: the entire point is that PCA will help you identify a smaller dimensional subspace that most of your data are close to.  **That's it.**  This is a mathematical characterization involving no assumptions whatsoever.

Comment: Then what is the use for kernel PCA? According to my searches it states that it is used if data is linearly inseparable.

Comment: That's a different beast with a different objective.

Comment: Could you please clarify what this objective is? Everything I'm reading states that kernel PCA is used if my data is nonlinear which is unclear because I don't know if they're talking about non-linear relationship or linearly **in**separable.

Comment: if your data has linear relationships then PCA works best. that's all. it doesn't mean it stops working when relationships are nonlinear. in reality we rarely know what are the relationships in data